Initializing the Flutter SDK. This may take a few minutes, still running..?
Initializing the Flutter SDK. This may take a few minutes,
Unable to create dart snapshot for flutter tool. Building flutter tool... Running pub upgrade... Resolving dependencies... (2.0s)
i reaDescribe what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually resulted

Please describe your issue in more detail.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
